# Defining click function based on dynamic name

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I am trying to define a dynamic function that performs action based on a button id that is incremented.

The code I wrote is as follow:

```
<script>
    var count = 1;

    function incrementCount(){
       count++;
    }

    $( "#submit_" + count.toString() ).click(function() {

        // Perform some actions before incrementing count
        // EDIT: 10-02-2020**
        $("button[id$='_" + (count).toString() + "']").fadeOut( "slow" );

        incrementCount();

        // Perform some actions after incrementing count
        // EDIT: 10-02-2020**
        $("div[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").fadeIn( "slow" );
        $("button[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").fadeIn( "slow" );

    }
)
</script>
```

My html as several submit tags labbeled as id="submit_1", "submit_2", "submit_3", ...

Unfortunately the above only works with "submit_1". Is there a way to achieve the above without having to explicitly define :

1. $( "#submit_1" ).click(function() {
2. $( "#submit_2" ).click(function() {
   ...

**EDIT: 12/02/2020 based on @VLAZ comment**

```
<script>
    var count = 1;

    function incrementCount(){
       count++;
    }

    $( "butt_sub" ).click(function() {

        $("button[id$='_" + (count).toString() + "']").fadeOut( "slow" );

        incrementCount();

        $("div[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").fadeIn( "slow" );
        $("button[id$='_" + count.toString() + "']").fadeIn( "slow" );

    }
)
</script>
```

with my html tag looking like:

```
<button id="submit_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="butt_sub" data-count="{{ forloop.counter }}" style="display: block;"/>Submission</button>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What you have right now doesn't logically track for a JS listener. Do you want to define a handler that defines another handler or do you want to define a whole bunch of handlers in one go?

Comment: Your incrementing doesn't work cause there's no loop.

Comment: @VLAZ Initially I wanted to define a handler that defines another handler recursively. But I realize that defining the whole bunch in one go would be fine too. If so, is it possible to wright a for loop around my $("#submit...?

Comment: @eric.p999 yes, it's possible. If you have something like `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) $("selector").click(/* ... */)` you'd be defining a bunch of click handlers at once. Five in my examples. If you use `$("selector" + i)` you'd target elements that have the same starting part and then have a number. Although, if you have *the same* logic for each handler and just want to use a loop for the selectors, it's usually better to have the same class or something on all, instead of numerically incrementing IDs, classes or whatever. It's easier to just do `$("common").click()`

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested but I might have done something wrong as it does not work. I edited the code to give you an overview of what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data property in the trigger element like `<div id="submit_1" class="classname" data-count="1">`. The value in the `data-count` should be the dynamic value in your submit button/element.

Then access it like:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(".classname").on('click', function() {
    var count = $(this).data('count');
    console.log(count);
    //$("#submit_"+count).whatever you wanna do here
  }); <
/script >
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="submit_1" class="classname" data-count="1">Submit1</div>
  <div id="submit_2" class="classname" data-count="2">Submit2</div>
  <div id="submit_3" class="classname" data-count="3">Submit3</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the above, but unfortunately the data-count attribute does not seem to be picked up. I cannot see it in the source code of the page generated. Any idea where it could come from?

Comment: I edited it. Try to check console.log in your debugger.

Comment: Could it be because I try to apply it to a button instead of a div like you? <button id="submit_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-count="{{ forloop.counter }}" style="display: none;"/>Submit</button>

Comment: I edited my code so that it contains what I aim to do after I click on the submit button. I display a div and the following button, while hiding the current submit button. Maybe it will make what I aim for clearer. :S

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;

$('input').click(function() {
  count++
})
```

If the goal is to just increment the count, the above code should work.

Or, if you want to keep the function,

```
$('input').click(incrementCount)
```

In the second example you can pass in a reference to your increment function, which will do the same thing.  The issue is that your selector never increments, so in essence you are only ever selecting `#submit_1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the above but could not make it work. Also I don't understand in how it differs from what I wrote. Could you explain?